# How do I SAVE as EXt JS-4 file

Tags: extjs

I am new  to EXT JS/4.Its a great tool, how do I save it though?

as.js file or some   Thing else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You write your code as javascript, so saving it as .js files makes sense.  Put those files in your app server/http server, whichever makes sense for your server platform.